# Rearranging JSON output in Laravel

Tags: json, laravel, eloquent

There are a few very similar questions, but not this exact thing. Let's start with my model:

- Contest (hasMany `Event`, belongsToMany `Player`)
- Player (hasMany `Event`, belongsToMany `Contest`, belongsToMany `Event`)
- Event (belongsTo `Contest`, belongsToMany `Players->withPivot('score)`)  (actually called `ContestEvent` since `Event` is a Laravel class)

I'm writing an API to do other stuff with the data. Right now I get this output from a given Contest:

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "owner_id": "1",
  "name": "Some Contest",
  "start_date": "2013-08-09",
  "end_date": "2013-08-31",
  "is_public": "1",
  "is_finished": "0",
  "players": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "first_name": "Bob",
      "last_name": "Smith",
      "initial_name": "Bob S",
      "pivot": {
        "contest_id": "1",
        "user_id": "1"
      }
    }
  ],
  "events": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Stage 1",
      "date": "2013-08-01",
      "players": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "first_name": "Bob",
          "last_name": "Smith",
          "initial_name": "Bob S",
          "pivot": {
            "contest_event_id": "1",
            "user_id": "1",
            "score": "5"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The `pivot` part is junk data, except for the `score` part under `events`. I can hide the whole `pivot` part with $hidden, but I want to access the `score` value one step up, outside of the `pivot` array.

I've messed around with `$append` and `getFooAttribute()`, but no success so far -- I can't quite figure out how to get Eloquent to do what I want. Any suggestions?

Comment: You will have to do some post processing after retrieving the Eloquent Collection. Think in terms of a loop and setting `$player->score = $player->pivot->score`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than rearranging my model, I discovered [Fractal](https://github.com/thephpleague/fractal), which made creating custom JSON output exactly the way you want it really easy.